# Boost numpy - how do I create a more complex dtype, such as datetime or object in C++?

Tags: python, c++, pandas, numpy, boost

I'm using Boost Numpy to create some arrays in C++ and pass to the Python namespace. Generally, I am creating them using this method:

```
namespace np = boost::python::numpy;
np::empty(shape, np::dtype::get_builtin<int>);
```

This works for the basic types like int, but I don't understand how I am supposed to do this for more complex types and the normal python object type.

For example, in python if I create a pandas DataFrame like this:

```
>>> pandas.DataFrame([datetime.datetime.now()])[0]
0   2020-11-17 20:30:06.132735
Name: 0, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

which gives me a DataFrame with a column of dtype: datetime64[ns].

Also, it would be useful to be able to create an np::empty with "object" type:

```
>>> pandas.DataFrame([None])[0]
0    None
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

How do I create these types of arrays in Boost Numpy from C++? The Boost documentation is very sparse and I can't seem to find any information about this online.